# pnp4nagios not logging performance data for new host

Tags: nagios

We've just updated Nagios from 3.5.x to the current version (4.0.7) and subsequently added a new host for monitoring.

The new host shows as 'Down' in Nagios, and this seems to be related to the fact that pnp4nagios is not logging performance data (the individual checks for users, http etc are all find).

Initially there was an error that the directory

```
/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/perfdata/newhost.com
```

that contains the xml setup and rrd files for the new host was missing), so I manually created this directory, but now it complains that the files are missing.

Does anyone know the appropriate steps to overcome this issue?

Thanks,

Toby

PS I'd tag this 'pnp4nagios', but that tag doesn't exist and I can't create them

**UPDATE**
It's possible that pnp4nagios is a red herring/symptom. Looking more closely I realise that Nagios actually believes the host is down, even though all services are up. The host status information is '(Host check timed out after 30.01 seconds)'...does this make any more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed very unlikely that pnp4nagios has something to do with your host being down. pnp actually exports output and performance data to feed the rrd database and xml files (via npcd module or evenhandler command).

The fact that nagios reports the host check timed out after 30 sec means that :
- you have a problem with your host check command, please double-check the syntax
- this check command times out after a certain timelapse (most likely defined in nagios.conf) because the plugin was still running.

I'd recommend running this command from the server's prompt. You want to do something like :

```
/path/to/libexec/check_command -H ipaddress -args
```

For example:

```
/usr/local/libexec/nagios/check_ping -H 192.168.1.1 -w 200,40% -c 500,80% -timeout 120
```

See if something might be hanging. Having the output would be helpful.

Once your host check returns correct output and performance data to nagios, pnp will hopefuly do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

In the unlikely event it helps anyone, pnp4nagios was indeed a red herring. The problem was that ping wasn't enabled for the host being checked, and this is the test for whether a host is up or not. Hence this was failing, despite other services being reported as working.